# Передача данных в глобальных переменных Java

Tags: java, android, переменные

В MainActivity объявляю переменную типа массив:

```
....
private String[] textitems;
    public String[] getTextitems(){
        return textitems;
    }
.....
```

Заполняю этот массив в цикле:

```
                           for (int i=0; i < items.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject item = (JSONObject) items.get(i);
                                String item_text = (String) item.get("text");
                                textitems[i] = item_text;

                            }
```

Объявляю его в другом классе:

```
private String[] textitems;
    public void setTextitems(String[] textitems){
        this.textitems = textitems;
    }
```

Вызываю:

```
...
           TextView tvPage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPage);
           tvPage.append(textitems[pageNumber]);
...
```

Насколько я все верно делаю?

Comment: Во-первых: вы должны понимать, что это две разные переменные и присвоение значения одной никак не влияет на вторую. Во-вторых: когда активность не на переднем плане (не видна) можете считать, что её не существует, так как менеджер памяти имеет полное право её уничтожить в любой момент  и, соответственно, все её переменные будут обнулены. Передавать данные между активностями нужно через интент, либо сохранять в файл, базу, преференсы и т.п., а во второй читать оттуда.

Comment: Мысль такая была. Ок. Спасибо за подсказку. Пойду через интент.

Answer (score 2):

1. Одноимённые переменные в двух разных классах - это две разные переменные и присвоение значения одной никак не влияет на вторую.
2. когда активность не на переднем плане (не видна) можете считать, что её не существует, так как менеджер памяти имеет полное право её уничтожить в любой момент и, соответственно, все её переменные будут обнулены.

Технически возможно записать значение в `static` поле и из другой активности получить их, но делать так тоже не желательно. Например, если пользователь свернул приложение, и системе понадобилось освободить память для других задач, то может быть выгружен весь процесс и по возвращению к нему будет запущена сразу последняя открытая активность и данных в этом поле уже не будет.

Передавать данные между активностями нужно через интент, либо сохранять в файл, базу, преференсы и т.п., а во второй читать оттуда.

В случае с интентом, даже если приложение будет выгружено, то по возвращению к нему активность получит тот же интент со всеми данными.